# Nodejs - socketio - update info in all browser windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events, socket.io

I just started up learning how to make web applications. I am making a webserver in nodejs (a to-do list app). I am using the express framework, and mongodb as database. For communication between the client and the server i am using socket.io.

I can't find a way to make it so that when the server emits and event the client will update the info on all of his open windows of the page. Right now the info updates only on the window that triggered the event on ther server. This is the server code:

## Server code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.of('/home').on('connection', function (socket) { 
    socket.on('newListGroup', function (data) {
        ...
        socket.emit('groupNo', obj);
    });
}); `
```

### Client javascript:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/login');
socke.on('groupNo', function(data){ ... });
$('#newListGroup').blur(function() {
    socketLogin.emit('newListGroup', {newGroup:newGroup});
});
```

Can this work or should I take another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can broadcast a message to all sockets like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.of('/home').on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('newListGroup', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('groupNo', obj); });
});
```

It should be limited to the namespace but you will probably have to implement your own logic for broadcasting only to windows on the same client (probably using authentication) if that is what you want to do.

Comment: I was looking into broadcasting, but wouldn't that send the message to all the connected clients ? (Clients are authenticated and have their info stored in a cookie.)

Comment: Yes, to all clients. I'm not even sure that what you seem to be wanting to do (only clients that connect from different browser windows on the same machine is how I understand it) is even possible. If it is just to authenticated clients you could just filter the sockets by their authentication information.

Comment: What i want is something like this. [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zf3uVGKKJW8). It's like when you have facebook opened in multiple windows(tabs), when you receive a new notification, the information in all windows(tabs) is updated, not just one of them.

Comment: That means you want to broadcast to all sockets with the same authentication information right? You can just store them in a `sockets[username] = [ socket1, socket2... ]` array during authentication and then go through all of them and emit the message again.